# 9-patch image not stretched

Tags: android, nine-patch

9-patch image is created, no more "bad patches" is shown. Seems in editor it is well set up. But in the screen the **png** image is placed, and not the stretched 9-patch file, what is the problem? Cleaned, rebuild project. I set up a red background color to see how wide is the imageview. "hello" is above the imageview.

```
holder.imageView.setX(dp10);
holder.imageView.setY(dp18);
holder.imageView.getLayoutParams().height = h+dp4;
holder.imageView.getLayoutParams().width = ww+dp20;
holder.imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

[image]

[image]

---

Coorected layout xml as @pskink suggested. Worked, but an other issue raised. See curves on the side of the bubble. Curves should look like as a circle, but now it is too stretched.

[image]

---

Here xml part:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bubbleblue170x140_2" />
```

And here is the 9-patch file:

[image]

[image]

Comment: use `"android:background"`, not `"android:src"`

Comment: Thanks @pskink, worked, an other issue raised. Could you take a look.

Comment: post the **whole** path with the saved 9 patch: <root>/res/...???

Comment: @pskink I think path in XML correct: `@drawable/bubbleblue170x140_2`

Comment: i had the same issue when i had `test.png` and `test.9.png` - i had to remove `test.png` and rebuild the whole project: something was broken

Comment: Did you know? you can use the 9 patch on a TextView, so to put the text inside it without having to make strange combinations of Views/ViewGroups. Just have ONE SINGLE View with the balloon and the text. But you must fix (reduce) your content area (right and bottom markers) in the 9 patch or the text will spread onto the outline.